# How to send JSON put with jeditable

Tags: json, jeditable

From what I understand of jeditable, the required parameter is the url where the newly edited data is posted. What I would like to do is send a JSON object using a http PUT. Is that possible?
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Jeditable API:

(String) method: Method to use when submitting edited content. Default is POST. You most likely want to use POST or PUT. PUT method is compatible with Rails.
http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable

You should be able to do:

```
$('.editable').editable('http://www.example.com/save.php', { 
     method : 'PUT',
     data : function() {
       var jsonString;
       //create json object
       return jsonString;
     }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks, but how would you specify the JSON object? I'm not using php, I just need to send the JSON object to a certain url. For example:
    http://foobar.net/api/foo/bar
    {name: 'foo', bar: 'hello'}

Comment: even if you create it as a string like -                             "{'x':'value','y':'value','z':'value'}" and while reading , read it using json object, it will work just fine

Comment: it is not very clea for me, how can i get the content of $('.editable') .

I try :
     jsonString = {
              title : $('titleEditable'),
              _id : myStufId
          };

But it doesn't work..

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can send data, but I would recommend sending it through POST . Send the data in the data field :-

`type:"POST"`

```
data: " {'x':'value','y':'value','z':'value'}"
```

and other fields like url etc.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should override ajaxoptions prop which is passed to extend $.ajax (jQuery):

```
oTable.$('td').editable( url, {
    "callback": function( sValue, y ) {
         your code
    },
    "submitdata": function ( value, settings ) {
         your code
    },
    "ajaxoptions": {"method": "PUT"}
} );
```

Seems jEditable native method setting supports PUT method via the "Rails way". So it is not actually a PUT request, but a POST request with a "_method" variable and "put" as value.
Some REST services won't work with this approach.

Comment: This should have been a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).